# Using on() handler on dynamic elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation where an element loads on the page(dynamically added by some third party) and have defined certain event for that element.

Below is the code which mimics the same situation where the `.on()` is not working on an element which I am adding dynamically.

What can be the issue here?

```js
// 1
$('#bhansa').click(function(){
  console.log('first');
})

// 2
$('.dom').on('click', '#bhansa', function(){
  console.log('second');
})

setTimeout(function(){
  $(".dom").html("<a href='#' id='bhansa'>Click me</a>");
}, 4000);

// 3
$('#bhansa').on('click', function(){
  console.log('last');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dom"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation on the `body` tag to make sure the event will not be detached when you `remove/add` parts to you DOM structure :

```
$('body').on('click', '#bhansa', function(){
     console.log('second');
})
```

As **@Taplar** comment says if the element that you are delegating binding on is being created dynamically, you are binding too low and should bind on a higher parent that is not dynamic `body`.

Comment: It should be noted that this can be accomplished without jQuery as well by simply inspecting the event's `target` property.

Comment: Added your comment to the post @Taplar , thanks for your intervention.

Comment: @FissureKing, the OP already using jQuery so suggesting a vanilla JS solution may unuseful in this case.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, fair enough. A JavaScript tag was also present but your point is well taken.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this correct if it works for my usecase.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that if you remove dom component, all listeners are removed also.

Try to add listener this way:

```
$("body").on("click", "#bhansa", () => {console.log(123)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this also:-

```
$(document).find().on('click', '#bhansa', function(){
    //code
});
```

Here document is Dom object.

Comment: I'm not sure if `find()` will work on dynamic element which is getting added later.